# Unable to increment field in mongodb using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, nosql

I have a document in mongodb. The document in This function is able to find the document and it returns it but I can't for the life of me get this function to update the count field by 1. The current document in mongodb if it helps is:

```
{
  _id: 60c5e4c3fba7edd232cf57e7,
  counterName: 'give_me_the_count',
  count: 1,
  updatedAt: 2021-06-13T11:47:02.575Z
}
```

The code is returning the original document to updatedCounter. But updatedCounter.count is undefined.

```
  async function updateAndReturnNewCount() {
  let doc = await Counter.findOne({ counterName : "give_me_the_count" })
  var count = doc.count
  let updatedCounter = await Counter.findOneAndUpdate({ counterName : "give_me_the_count" },
                           { $inc: {"count" : 1 }},
                           { new: true,
                            useFindAndModify: false },
                            function(err, doc) {
                              if (err) { console.log(err)}
                              else {console.log("success")}
                            }
                           );
  console.log("updateAndReturnNewCount fired")
  return updatedCounter.count
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your query is incorrect for the operation you wanted to do.

Try this one:

```
await Counter.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      counterName : "give_me_the_count"
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      "count": {
        $add: [ "$count", 1 ] // Increment $count by one
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/I6mFJa33Lw2)

Edit:

Usage:

```
 async function updateAndReturnNewCount() {
  let doc = await Counter.findOne({ counterName : "give_me_the_count" })
  var count = doc.count
  let updatedCounter = await Counter.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      counterName : "give_me_the_count"
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      "count": {
        $add: [ "$count", 1 ] // Increment $count by one
      }
    }
  }
])
  console.log("updateAndReturnNewCount fired");
  console.log(updatedCounter);
  return count++;
}
```

Comment: @Marko I updated my anser. Showed usage to you.